# brownie.exceptions.EventLookupError: Event 'xxx' did not fire

Tags: solidity, events, ganache, brownie, event-handling

I am testing my contracts with brownie on local ganache and hit an issue where my events are not firing. When I call

```
tx.events['xxx']['param1']
```

I get error:

> brownie.exceptions.EventLookupError: Event 'xxx' did not fire

The issue is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68432609/contract-event-listener-is-not-firing-when-running-hardhat-tests-with-ethers-js) which was run on hardhat/ethers.js. Is there an equivalent solution for brownie?

Here is what I got when I ran `tx.info()`:

```
Transaction was Mined 
---------------------
Tx Hash: 0x367e6943d7c86aea16256fbe14af2d6b344add959d4b32e509053898d2b12d8f
From: 0x66aB6D9362d4F35596279692F0251Db635165871
To: 0xe0aA552A10d7EC8760Fc6c246D391E698a82dDf9
Value: 0
Function: Transaction
Block: 27
Gas Used: 245398 / 12000000 (2.0%)

Events In This Transaction
--------------------------
└── MyContract (0xe0aA552A10d7EC8760Fc6c246D391E698a82dDf9)
    └── (unknown)
        ├── topic1: 0x04c4f3cde1cd8ce89a8c0cfed8996313677b623e5b9d0aa6c8672274d7a4c64a
        ├── topic2: 0x00000000000000000000000066ab6d9362d4f35596279692f0251db635165871
        ├── topic3: 0x4d724b83403c1c14bd52d9a72d392d6f4d3d5dc63fe7fbeb8cee40a17f2183a6
        └── data: 0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000053843b1d824d0000
```

My event has 3 params, of which the first two are `indexed`. It seems that my event data can be found in the transaction info, without its name `(unknown)`.

Comment: Any luck resolving this? I'm hitting the same issue...

Comment: @rbinnun solve it. I defined my event in a library .sol file and emitted the event in a internal function in the library. So when my contract called the internal function, the event emitted but brownie could not interpret the event since was not compiled properly. So best practice is just to not define/call event in library.

Answer (score 0):

I have the some issue in no answer ^^'
So the problem raise because of the logic of your smart contract.
You need to try to resolve the logic issue in your smart contract than re-try to run the script again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this occurs when brownie is not registering the ABI encoding of the event.

A solution that works for me is by ensuring the event is in an interface which is stored in the folder `<brownie-root>/interfaces/`.

e.g. `<brownie-root>/interfaces/IMyContract.sol`

```
interface IMyContract {
    event xxx(address index param1, ...);
}
```

Other cases I've noticed this occurs is if it's a 3rd party contract that's not in the `<brownie-root>/contractrs/` directory. In which case either a) move the contract into `<brownie-root>/contracts/` or create an interface in `<brownie-root>/interfaces/` with the desired event.